# Open a local file from an Xcode mac application

Tags: macos

I'm making a mac application in interface builder, and was wondering how I would go about assigning a button to open a file.

Specifically, I'm trying to make a file launch (it's an installer file) when I click a button on my Xcode application. How might I go about this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Write `IBAction` method for button.

```
- (IBAction)install:(id)sender;
{
// your code for installer file..
}
```

[image]